# url pattern syntax (java servlet)

Tags: java, servlets, url-pattern

I want to do something like this:

> localhost:7001/servlet/character?name=zombies

I tried doing this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>zombies</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/character?name=zombies</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

but it doesn't work and giving me not found error. Any advice or solution on how to do it?

Comment: Apart from the corrections in `web.xml`, is your application called `servlet`? I aks because that was a feature in old versions of Tomcat and I don't think it's there anymore.

Comment: Oh no, it was a example.

Answer (score 1):

The `?name=zombies` portion of your url-pattern should not be used in the `web.xml`. It is a query parameter that is not actually a part of the servlet mount point. You would need to access the variable `name` in your zombies servlet via `request.getParameter("name")`.

Comment: Thanks. I am a bit new to servlet programming. Didn't realize it was a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to append **query string** the stuff followed by **?** with your **URL pattern**. 
URL pattern is meant to map your servlet class. if you can pass query string in the address bar itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a parameter to your servlet then do like this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>zombies</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ZombiesDemo</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>name</param-name>
        <param-value>zombies</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>zombies</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/character</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This you can retrive in ZombiesDemo.java servlet as

```
public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException{
  String name = servletConfig.getInitParameter("name");
  }
```

Comment: is it possible to do multiple param-values? so let say i enter url/character?name=zombie, it would appear page with text then after i enter url/character?name=pirates, it would appear the same page with different text. OR i would have to create another servlet just for pirates?

Comment: No, it for initialization values to servlet. If you want this then pass these values in request scope using request.setAttribute("name","pirates"); and request.setAttribute("name");